# Cannot import react native API because of module parse error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, webpack, mui-x

I tried to import [react-native-lyric](https://github.com/hoanganhken97/react-native-lyric)  inside [MUI](https://mui.com/) box but got error shown below when I run `npm web start`.

```
Failed to compile.

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:7)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> export type {LrcLine} from './constant';
| 
| export {default as Lyric} from './components/lyric';
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-lyric/src/index.ts 1:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:7)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> export type {LrcLine} from './constant';
| 
| export {default as Lyric} from './components/lyric';
```

To fix the issue I tried making the following change to package.json

```
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ]
  }
```

Run `npm cache clean --force` and `rm -rf node_modules && rm -f package-lock.json && npm i`
still the same error.

Comment: wich version of react-native-lyric are you using?

Comment: 1.0.2 but I don't think this matters as I use the same in another bare-bone project and it works. I'm thinking it is something to do with tsx and babel?

Comment: can you share your babel and tsconfig?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try adding the `babel-loader` to your project if it's not already included, so install it like below

```
npm install babel-loader --save-dev
```

or

```
yarn add babel-loader --dev
```

and make sure it is properly configured in your webpack or babel configuration, and also make sure that you have the latest versions of the loaders you are using in your project because outdated loaders might have compatibility issues!
you can update the loaders by running

```
npm update
```

or

```
yarn upgrade
```

also check your `tsconfig.json` file and make sure that the necessary TypeScript options are set, such as the target version and module resolution!

good luck !

Answer (score -2):

It seems like the `react-native-lyric` package you're trying to import might not be compatible with the version of Node.js you're using. Check the package's documentation and the release notes to see if there are any specific requirements or compatibility issues for your Node.js version.

Additionally, you might want to try clearing the cache and reinstalling the package using the following commands:

```
npm cache clean --force
rm -rf node_modules
npm i
```

Or if that doesn't work, try uninstalling and reinstalling the entire package:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm uninstall react-native-lyric -S
rm -rf node_modules/react-native-lyric
npm install
```

And also make sure your Node.js version is the latest that is available:

```
# Using a package called "n"
npm install n -g

# Update Node.js to the latest version
n latest

# Update NPM to the latest version
npm install npm -g
```

If you're still encountering the same error, you can try starting an "Issue" on the [package's GitHub](https://github.com/hoanganhken97/react-native-lyric). The owner might be able to provide more insight into the specific issue and provide solutions to resolve it.

Comment: Okay good, then I withdraw my object. Thank you for helping.

Comment: No problem. I hate AI generated answers as well, lol.